# Operation could destabilize the runtime in mvc3 razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am working in mvc3 razor my project fistly run correctly but i get the error

```
Error   3   Assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,     PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' uses 'System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,     PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced     assembly 'System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'        c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Web.Mvc.dll    MvcApplication1
```

and i replace the system.web.mvc.dll and System.Web.WebPages.Razor files from mvc4 folder to mvc3 folder. and some changes in web.config and it start working correctly. but now after few days it show me the following error message

Operation could destabilize the runtime

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Security.VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the runtime.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

```
Stack Trace: 


[VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the runtime.]
System.Web.Mvc.Razor.MvcWebPageRazorHost.GetRidOfNamespace(String ns) +32
System.Web.Mvc.Razor.MvcWebPageRazorHost..ctor(String virtualPath, String physicalPath) +196
System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory.CreateHost(String virtualPath, String physicalPath) +113
System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebRazorHostFactory.CreateHostFromConfigCore    (RazorWebSectionGroup        config, String virtualPath, String physicalPath) +422
System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebRazorHostFactory.CreateHostFromConfig(String virtualPath, String physicalPath) +228
System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebRazorHostFactory.CreateHostFromConfig(String virtualPath) +38
System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.GetHostFromConfig() +51
System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.CreateHost() +57
System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.get_Host() +56
System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.EnsureGeneratedCode() +92
System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.get_CodeCompilerType() +54
System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetCompilerTypeFromBuildProvider(BuildProvider buildProvider) +59
System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.ProcessBuildProviders() +209
System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() +15
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath) +9929933
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) +299
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) +103
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound) +165
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetObjectFactory(String virtualPath, Boolean throwIfNotFound) +33
System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerWrapper.System.Web.Mvc.IBuildManager.FileExists(String virtualPath) +40
System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerViewEngine.FileExists(ControllerContext controllerContext, String virtualPath) +54
System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.GetPathFromGeneralName(ControllerContext controllerContext, List1     
locations, String name, String controllerName, String areaName, String cacheKey, String[]& searchedLocations) +197
System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.GetPath(ControllerContext controllerContext, String[] locations, String[] areaLocations, String locationsPropertyName, String name, String   controllerName, String cacheKeyPrefix, Boolean useCache, String[]& searchedLocations) +681
System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext,  String     viewName, String masterName, Boolean useCache) +315
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassc.<FindView>b__b(IViewEngine e) +68
System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.Find(Func2 lookup, Boolean trackSearchedPaths) +182
System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.Find(Func2 cacheLocator, Func2 locator) +110
System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String     viewName, String masterName) +329
System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult.FindView(ControllerContext context) +135
System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +230
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +39
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +74
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, 
Func1 continuation) +388
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__1b() +72
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext,IList1filters, ActionResult actionResult) +303
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +844
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +130
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +229
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +39
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +71
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +44
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8
1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +42
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult
1.End() +152
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +75
System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +31
System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +61
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +118
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9629708
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

settings in my web.config are as under

```
<assemblies>
<add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
 <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
 <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
 <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
 <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  </assemblies>
```

Please any one give me help about this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed .NET Framework 4.5 or Visual Studio 2012? The problem is most likely a bug in the framework. You may find your answers here:

http://elegantcode.com/2012/08/23/net-4-5-operation-could-destabilize-the-runtime-yikes/

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue with one of our projects.  We had been using MVC3 and tried upgrading to MVC4.  We also upgraded to Razor 2.0.  Turned out that the web.configs did not all update as expected.  Check your web config in the ~/Views folder as well as the root web.config and make sure the assembly binding redirects are correct and all the assembly references are correct.  We did that and the issue went away